# Passing Parameters to a List new item form based on connected view

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt-list-view-web-part, connected-web-parts

I am trying to build a set of SharePoint 2016/Online Pages that interact with a set of lists to facilitate a particular way of interacting and adding data.

What I am currently building is a page with 4 webparts (using the standard 3 column template) -

**Left Web Part**

*Country List - XsltListViewWebPart*

Simple list showing just the country name

**Center Web Part**

*Make List - XsltListViewWebPart*

The columns for this list are Make Name and Country and the contents of this are filtered based on the country selected in the previous view using the *'Get Filter Values From'* connection

**Right Web Part**

*Model List - XsltListViewWebPart*
The column names for this are Model Name, Make Name and the contents of this are filtered based on the make selected in the previous view using the *'Get Filter Values From'* connection

**Bottom Center Web Part**

*Derivative List - XsltListViewWebPart*

The columns for this are Derivative Name, Model Name and Country where the contents of this list are filtered based on the Country selected in the Country list and the model selected in the Model list (both using the *'Get Filter Values From'* connection).

**Issue**

All of the interactions defined above seem to work as expected but I have now hit something I want to do that I can't seem to implement.

I have turned the ability to add new items in the Country, Make and Model XsltListViewWebPart's off however I want this feature to remain for the 
Derivative List with one alteration in that I want when a new item is created for the country, make and model fields to be automatically populated based on the filter values applied from the other views.

I really cannot see how to do this.

- Can you pass parameters to forms (E.g. these filter values)?
- Should a new form be created for that rather than changing the detault
  NewForm.aspx to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes, you can pass parameters to forms

2.- you can do both:

use the querystring filter webpart to extract paramenters from the url and then add them to the form

use InfoPath form to include parameters on the form

also you'll have to set up how to send the paramenter: you can create your own custom hyperlink or customize the new item button :

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/75c9163e-485d-4f6c-867f-49fffb7548b8/passing-id-variable-from-the-parent-to-the-child-new-item-form?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious